# Maximal quotient group of direct product

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, quotient-group, gap, direct-product

In GAP small group library, The group $$[32,2]=\langle a,b,c\mid a^4=b^4=c^2=1, ba=abc, [a,c]=[b,c]=1 \rangle.$$

We say $G/N$ is a maximal quotient group if there exists no quotient group $G/K$ such that $G/N$ is isomorphic to a quotient group of $G/K$.

Use GAP, we found that $[32,2]\times C_2$ has the maximal nonabelian quotient group which is isomorphic to  $[32,2], [32,22]$ or $[32,23]$; the group $[32,2]\times C_2\times C_2$ has the maximal nonabelian  quotient group which is isomorphic to  $[32,2]\times C_2, [32,22]\times C_2$ or $[32,23]\times C_2$. Define $n$-copy direct product of $C_2$ by $C_2^n$.

I have following Question: is it possible to prove that if $H$ is a maximal quotient group of $[32,2]\times C_2^n$, then $H$ is isomorphic to  $[32,2]\times C_2^{n-1}, [32,22]\times C_2^{n-1}$ or $[32,23]\times C_2^{n-1}$.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Could you say exactly what you mean by a "maximal nonabelian quotient" of a group $G$? Do you mean a nonabelian quotient of $G$ of the form $G/N$ where $N$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G$?  If so, then isn't the answer to yoru question obviously yes? Also I don't really understand what you mean by "(isomorphic)".

Comment: Is ste statement you want to prove for $G=[32,2]\times C_2^n$: "If $N\lhd G$ with $G/N$ nonabelian, then $G/N$ is isomorphic to one of the 3 indicated types"?

Comment: @DerekHolt I rewrite my question. Hopefully this time the question is more readable.  I am sorry that I did't see the obviously.

Comment: @ahulpke Thanks for your time. Using GAP, I found that $[32,2]×C_2^3$ has a quotient group $Q_8\times C_2^2$.

Comment: Presumably you want to assume that $N$ is non-trivial in your definition of maximal abelian quotient? I think your definition is equivalent to "quotient by a minimal normal subgroup" (at least for finite groups).

Comment: But $Q_8 \times C_2^2$ cannot be a maximal quotient of $[32,2] \times C_2^3$.